# gsub with regular expression removes one character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, gsub

I have an article model (article.rb):

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :content
end
```

I have a `gsub` like this in my article.rb:

```
self.content.gsub!(/anylink[^']/i, "<%= link_to 'anylink', 'http://website.com/anylink' %>")
```

This substitutes the word `"anylink"` in the text of an article with the `"link_to 'anylink', 'http://website.com/anylink'"` to create an automatic link. When there is already a `"link_to..."`, it will NOT substitute since I excluded the `'` after anylink in the regular expression.

It works, but the problem is that it deletes the next character following `"anylink"`. E.g. it converts:

```
"Have a look at anylink and see"
```

to

```
"Have a look at anylinkand see"
```

`"anylink"` in this second phrase now is a hyperlink, so everything is fine except the missing space that has been deleted during the `gsub` operation. Any ideas why and how I can avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

[`String#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) replaces the whole matching part of your pattern with your replacement, which is here the `anylink` string **and** one character which is not an apostrophe.

So it would replace the following Strings for example:

- `anylinkA`
- `anylink.`
- `anylink!`

If you want to keep your character, you could create a match and put that after the replacement:

```
self.content.gsub!(/anylink([^'])/i, "<%= link_to 'anylink', 'http://website.com/anylink' %>\\1")
```

Here the matching group `([^'])` will match on the character and the escaped `\1` will put that char after your replacement.

But I recommend you to use the `\b` to match the [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
self.content.gsub!(/\banylink\b/i, "<%= link_to 'anylink', 'http://website.com/anylink' %>")
```

So with this solution the word anylink will be replaced by the `gsub` and it can be preceded or followed any character but not an alphanumeric.

If you want to replace all matches in `self.content`, add `g` regexp modifier:

```
self.content.gsub!(/\banylink\b/ig, "<%= link_to 'anylink', 'http://website.com/anylink' %>")
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't fully understand the first solution, adding the \\1 at the end of the line didn't change behavor. The second suggestion works fine for the first time I edit the article, but then the second time it substitutes the "link_to 'anylink', 'http...' with "link_to 'link_to 'anylink', http...', http...'. Thats why I excluded the execution of gsub if there is a ' at the end of the word (gsub!(/anylink([^'])/i, etc...)

Comment: You did not mention that you're running the replacement multiple times on your content. If you do that, it would replace the `anylink` string every time. So there will be a link inside a link.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mentioning it. That's why I have the /anylink([^'])/ regex which in principle solves the problem. As I said, it just also deletes the character behind, that's the main problem.

Comment: Why do you need to do the replacement multiple times? Why don't just add `g` regexp modifier to my second solution to replace all?

Comment: The thing is that I have an encyclopedia where articles might change and be updated. When I do the update it needs to check the new content of the article if it contains certain keywords, but it need to keep the old link_to's as they were. Not a simple problem, but the [^'] solved this quite well, just the removed charater remains the problem.

Comment: user929062, then have a try with this, which expands @KARASZIIstván solution:  
    `gsub!(/(anylink)([^'])/i, "<%= link_to '\\1','http://website.com/\\1' %>\\2")`
it might solve the issue